# How to avoid warning while running the batch file in C#

Tags: c#, process, batch-file, scheduler

In this code, I am creating the batch file and run this file through c#.
While running the batch file, if the task name xxx is there, it will show "are you sure to delete the task" by clicking yes, it will execute the remaining lines in the batch file.

Is it possible to give yes automatically?If so please give your thoughts.

```
    string schCmd = string.Format("SchTasks /Delete /TN xxx \n schtasks /create /tn xxx " +
                                                "/tr {0} /sd  {1} /st {2} /sc DAILY /mo {3} \n PAUSE"
                                                ,           Server.MapPath("SqlScripts/sqlbackup.bat"), startDate, objAutoBackup.StartTime, objAutoBackup.Occurences);                   

    sw.WriteLine(schCmd);
    sw.Close();

    System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
    proc.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Server.MapPath("SqlScripts");

    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;                  

    proc.StartInfo.FileName = "scheduler.bat";
    proc.Start();
```

Comment: use the /F switch for delete. It forcefully deletes the task and uppresses warnings if the specified task is currently running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `/f` switch for `schtasks` to delete the task with prompting.

> A value that forcefully deletes the task and suppresses warnings if the specified task is running.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/bb736357%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @karthik Great, no worries.

Answer (score 0):

From
[Schtasks On microsoft.com](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/schtasks.mspx?mfr=true)

Use the *Force* flag:

/f : Suppresses the confirmation message. The task is deleted without warning.

Example:

schtasks /delete /tn * /f